# IIS on windows2019 may be dropping some transactions

Tags: .net-core, iis

I have one dotnet core webapi and deployed on windows2019/IIS, it receives the transactions from a sender and send back the acknowledgment.
I am experience an issue where sender is complaining that some time they are receiving time-out issue, means application is not sending the acknowledgement to sender.

The transactions which is giving the time-out issue is not showing in my application log file (I am recording each and every entry) and on IIS level there is no error.
Not sure these time-out transactions are dropped on IIS level or it is not reached to IIS.

I checked the logs of IIS and applied the lock in the method which receives HTTPPost

Comment: What transactions are you talking about? Distributed Transactions? How did you implement them?

Comment: IIS is recieving some json files using HTTPPOST and HTTPPut

Comment: So your calls time out? You said something about transactions?

Comment: And what does a `lock` have to do with it?

Comment: yes calls are dropped..but not sure it is iis issue or not

Comment: lock statement i used in my application so that if multiple requests reach to my method then it should be handled one at a time

Comment: Well, we have really *zero* information to help you here. Did you write logs? How long until something times out? How long does your method take? Maybe it just takes longer sometimes?

Comment: Well, why is that? If one request has to wait for other requests, it will obviously time out after a while if it has to wait too long... why can't they be handled in parallel? I'm sure your server has more than one core.

Comment: can we know what data iis is receiving on each call?

Comment: IIS only logs high level information for requests processed by the web server like the user's IP address, URL requested, and the status code that was returned (200,404, etc). Maybe you need some network packet sniffer tool? Something like wiredshark.